# Use Semantic UI's Visibility for infinite scrolling within an overflowing div

Tags: semantic-ui

I want to make use of [Infinite Scrolling using the Semantic UI Visibility Behavior](https://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/visibility.html#/examples) but within an `overflow-y: auto` div rather than in relation to the whole page. Here is a simplified version of my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <!-- lots of lines of content -->
  <p class="myElementWithinDiv">Alert should appear when this is visible</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#myDiv {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.myElementWithinTheDiv')
    .visibility({
        once: false,
        observeChanges: true,
        onTopVisible: function() {
            console.log('top visible');
        }
});
```

JSFiddle of the above working ***without*** the CSS restricting the DIV height: https://jsfiddle.net/jtge3s2o/

JSFiddle of the above *not working* ***with*** the CSS restricting the DIV height: https://jsfiddle.net/wznxkef2/2/

Is there a way to make this work with the `div` set to a fixed height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Behavior's Settings](https://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/visibility.html#/settings) the context can be set as follows:

```
$('.myElementWithinTheDiv')
    .visibility({
        once: false,
        context: document.getElementById('myDiv'),
        observeChanges: true,
        onTopVisible: function() {
            console.log('top visible');
        }
});
```